# jQuery $(this) childern

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I select child elements of this:

```
<ul id="menu">
 <li>
   <a href="#">a</a>
 </li>
 <li>
   <a href="#">b</a>
 </li>
 <li>
   <a href="#">b</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#menu ul li').each(function () {
            $(this).hover(function () {
                // HERE I WANT SELECT "a" , $(this).a OR SOMETHING LIKE THAT
            });
        });
```

I want to add animation on all "a" if their "li" is selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$(this).find('a')` or `$(this).children('a')` or `$('a', this)`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#menu ul li').each(function () {
            $(this).hover(function () {
                $('a', $(this))
            });
        });
```

Comment: It's `$(this)` because `$()` adds support to jQuery methods. That is, `this.hover` is invalid, while `$(this).hover` works.

Comment: There is no need to wrap `this` when using it as the context argument of `$(selector, context)`.